# Grouping data by name and date ranges

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have data in my oracle table where I have names and date rages as following:

```
Name                From        To
Lopes, Janine       07-Jun-17   16-Jul-17
Lopes, Janine       17-Jul-17   23-Jul-17
Lopes, Janine       24-Jul-17   31-Aug-17
Baptista, Maria     23-Dec-16   19-Feb-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    22-Jan-17   18-Apr-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    27-Apr-17   14-May-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    15-May-17   21-May-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    22-May-17   28-May-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    29-May-17   31-May-17
Serrentino, Joyce   18-Mar-17   30-Apr-17
More, Cathleen      30-Jul-17   13-Aug-17
More, Cathleen      14-Aug-17   20-Aug-17
More, Cathleen      21-Aug-17   27-Aug-17
More, Cathleen      28-Aug-17   03-Sep-17
More, Cathleen      04-Sep-17   10-Sep-17
More, Cathleen      11-Sep-17   24-Sep-17
Barrows, Michael    30-Jan-17   19-Mar-17
Barrows, Michael    20-Mar-17   26-Mar-17
Barrows, Michael    27-Mar-17   02-Apr-17
Barrows, Michael    03-Apr-17   07-Apr-17
```

Mostly for one user the to date is one greater than from date and is continuous but in some cases there is break the data so my output should look like this:

```
Name                From            To
Lopes, Janine       07-Jun-17   31-Aug-17
Baptista, Maria     23-Dec-16   19-Feb-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    22-Jan-17   18-Apr-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas    27-Apr-17   31-May-17
Serrentino, Joyce   18-Mar-17   30-Apr-17
More, Cathleen      30-Jul-17   24-Sep-17
Barrows, Michael    30-Jan-17   07-Apr-17
```

If I do min(from) and max(to) I loose some records like for Thomas.
How should I write sql to get the data is I require.

Comment: Here is a way to do it in sql server http://rextester.com/EVU37046. This should give you an idea to start with. Replace the function with relevant oracle functions

Comment: Are you looking for the total number of days for a person based on actual entries or the total number of days from From to To?

Comment: @Shawn I am looking to get the the groupings by having from and to date as max(from) and max(to) if there are no breaks in the date range but if there is a break i want it to start a new range

Comment: Gotcha, I misread the question at first and thought you were looking for number of days. You may be able to use LEAD or LAG functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 and above, `the MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause does quick work of such requirements. I am using the same setup and simulated data (WITH clause) from my other answer, and the output is also the same.

```
select name, date_fr, date_to
from   inputs
match_recognize(
  partition by name
  order by date_fr
  measures a.date_fr     as date_fr,
           last(date_to) as date_to
  pattern ( a b* )
  define b as date_fr = prev(date_to) + 1
)
;
```

Comment: @Auguster - I agree that this should work best **IF** you have Oracle 12 or above (which you do). I wrote the Tabibitosan method first, before I realized you tagged with `oracle12c`. By the time I wrote the `match_recognize` solution, the other one was already upvoted, which means people found it helpful, so I decided to keep it (instead of deleting). But on Oracle 12 people should use `match_recognize`, not the older approaches.

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution to this problem. When I was working with Oracle, I sometimes came across things that made me wonder why they couldn't do it like Microsoft TSQL does. Then there are things like this that make me wonder why MS can't do things this way.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved nicely with the Tabibitosan method.

Preparation:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-Mon-rr';

Session altered.
;
```

Query (including simulated inputs for convenience):

```
with
     inputs ( name, date_fr, date_to ) as (
       select 'Lopes, Janine'    , to_date('07-Jun-17'), to_date('16-Jul-17') from dual union all
       select 'Lopes, Janine'    , to_date('17-Jul-17'), to_date('23-Jul-17') from dual union all
       select 'Lopes, Janine'    , to_date('24-Jul-17'), to_date('31-Aug-17') from dual union all
       select 'Baptista, Maria'  , to_date('23-Dec-16'), to_date('19-Feb-17') from dual union all
       select 'Deyak,Sr, Thomas' , to_date('22-Jan-17'), to_date('18-Apr-17') from dual union all
       select 'Deyak,Sr, Thomas' , to_date('27-Apr-17'), to_date('14-May-17') from dual union all
       select 'Deyak,Sr, Thomas' , to_date('15-May-17'), to_date('21-May-17') from dual union all
       select 'Deyak,Sr, Thomas' , to_date('22-May-17'), to_date('28-May-17') from dual union all
       select 'Deyak,Sr, Thomas' , to_date('29-May-17'), to_date('31-May-17') from dual union all
       select 'Serrentino, Joyce', to_date('18-Mar-17'), to_date('30-Apr-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('30-Jul-17'), to_date('13-Aug-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('14-Aug-17'), to_date('20-Aug-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('21-Aug-17'), to_date('27-Aug-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('28-Aug-17'), to_date('03-Sep-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('04-Sep-17'), to_date('10-Sep-17') from dual union all
       select 'More, Cathleen'   , to_date('11-Sep-17'), to_date('24-Sep-17') from dual union all
       select 'Barrows, Michael' , to_date('30-Jan-17'), to_date('19-Mar-17') from dual union all
       select 'Barrows, Michael' , to_date('20-Mar-17'), to_date('26-Mar-17') from dual union all
       select 'Barrows, Michael' , to_date('27-Mar-17'), to_date('02-Apr-17') from dual union all
       select 'Barrows, Michael' , to_date('03-Apr-17'), to_date('07-Apr-17') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select name, min(date_fr) as date_fr, max(date_to) as date_to
from   ( select name, date_fr, date_to,
                date_to - sum( date_to - date_fr + 1 ) over (partition by name 
                                                            order by date_fr) as gr
         from   inputs
       )
group by name, gr
order by name, date_fr
;
```

Output:

```
NAME              DATE_FR   DATE_TO 
----------------- --------- ---------
Baptista, Maria   23-Dec-16 19-Feb-17
Barrows, Michael  30-Jan-17 07-Apr-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas  22-Jan-17 18-Apr-17
Deyak,Sr, Thomas  27-Apr-17 31-May-17
Lopes, Janine     07-Jun-17 31-Aug-17
More, Cathleen    30-Jul-17 24-Sep-17
Serrentino, Joyce 18-Mar-17 30-Apr-17

 7 rows selected
```

Comment: For those interested: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680  >> From Final Paragraph: `The one thing to remember though is, if you're considering how to group sequences of values into 'ranges', then think "Tabibitosan" !!`. Than it also says if your version is >= 12c, then use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. ^^